# How to show python environment objects in a pane in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In R Studio, Matlab, and in some Python IDEs (like Thonny) you can see a list of the variables in your environment, together with some summary information like values, type etc.

Is there a way to do this in VSCode without going into debugging mode?

Comment: As far as I am aware the only way you can is in debugging mode, the way I like to do it is attach a break point to the relevant lines and views variables in the debug panel or by hovering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the closest as it gets to the RStudio Environment window is by installing Jupyter. Then you can type `#%%` in your .py file and a small "Run Cell" button will appear. Running the cell will open the "Python Interactive Window". There you can click the "See Variables Active" button to open up the Variable Window and see your variables... still a bit painful in comparison with RStudio, this should be integrated in VScode's IDE.

See steps here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py#_variable-explorer-and-data-viewer

Answer (score 1):

VS Code has an IPython mode with a dropdown box called *Variables* that basically does exactly this.

To enter IPython mode all you need to do is highlight a piece of code and hit *Shift+Enter*

The first time you do it there might be a bit of setting up to do but it was pretty easy to get it working on my Mac. Not sure what it's like on Windows/Linux though

***Note:*** When I use VS Code I open it from the terminal (simply enter the command 'code') after I've activated my conda environment. That way the IPython interpreter uses my preferred conda environment when it launches.